# Как прочитать массив float из памяти?

Tags: c++

Делаю dll inject в процесс, в нем нужно прочитать структуру VMatrix из адреса 0x1006B40.

```
typedef float VMatrix[4][4];

VMatrix worldToScreen = 0x1006B40;
```

Как это сделать?
Чтобы в дальнейшем я мог использовать:

```
screen.x = worldToScreen[0][0] * point[0] + worldToScreen[0][1] * point[1] + worldToScreen[0][2] * point[2] + worldToScreen[0][3];
screen.y = worldToScreen[1][0] * point[0] + worldToScreen[1][1] * point[1] + worldToScreen[1][2] * point[2] + worldToScreen[1][3];
```

Answer (score 2):

привести адрес к указателю:

```
VMatrix * worldToScreen = (VMatrix *)0x1006B40;
```